# Getting vsbuild error while pushing asp.net code into azure devops

Tags: asp.net, git, azure-devops

Iam trying to push my asp.net(mvc) code azure devops using Git bash, but I am getting VSBuild error saying:

```
Error: Preparing the test sources file failed. 
Error: No test sources found matching the given filter '**\*test*.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**'
VsTest task failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

That error should be separate from a `git push`.
Meaning:

- you are pushing your sources
- but your Azure pipeline might not be correctly configured

See this [thread for instance](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/547869/no-test-sources-found-matching-the-given-filter-in.html):

> From this error (`No test sources found matching the given filter '**\*,!**\obj\*'`), we can see that you release pipeline do not get the build Artifacts sources.
> So you need add a "Copy Files" task before your publish task in the build pipeline:

[image: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/storage/attachments/71128-copy-files.png]

> Or add a "Copy Files" task before your "VsTest" task in the release pipeline.
>
> If it still an issue for you, please share your Organization name and log in account.(please choose "viewable by Microsoft Only")

See also "[Publishing test assemblies with artifacts in order to use them during functional tests on VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51535782/6309)", and [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/349742/vstest-in-release-pipeline-cant-find-tests-no-test.html), which illustrates a correct pipeline configuration:

[image: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/storage/attachments/43638-copyfiletask.png]

Answer (score 0):

From the error we know that Vstest task failed to find the test assemblies.

It may because the test files you defined in **Test Files** field is incorrect, or you specified a wrong **search folder** where the test assemblies are not exist. For below example. Vstest task will search for all the files that matching `*test*.dll` in folder $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)(eg. `c:/agent/_work/1/s`). Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to find more predefined variables.

[image]

The fix is simple if you know where the test assemblies is copied by VsBuild task. You can check the log of **Visual Studio Build** task, to find out where the test.dll files are located.

[image]
[image]

Hope you find above helpful.

Comment: Something in Azure DevOps seems to have changed. Having no test files produced a warning last week, but it now produces an error

Comment: For this case, Microsoft developer is currently workin on a hotfix. You can join in this [thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/6577). Since you 
 donot have test files in your project, you can disable vstest for now as workaround.